# AVRO schema with default array of objects

Tags: avro

I have an AVRO schema with an array field. This array field has items being an object of another AVRO schema. Below is the code I have right now.

```
{
  "name": "bars",
  "type": ["null", {
    "type": "array",
    "items": "com.example.Bar"
  }],
  "default": null
}
```

This code is the field definition for "bars" which is an array containing "com.example.Bar" objects.

I have the default set as "null" for now, however I would like to explicitly set the default value to be an array of 3 Bar objects.

Imagine my Bar has the following fields definition

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "type": [
    "null",
    "string"
  ],
  "default": null
},
{
  "name": "number",
  "type": [
    "null",
    "int"
  ],
  "default": null
}
```

I would like to set the "bars" default to be

```
{
  "name": "bars",
  "type": ["null", {
    "type": "array",
    "items": "com.example.Bar"
  }],
  "default": [{"name": "bar1", "number":1}, {"name": "bar2", "number":2}, {"name": "bar3", "number":3}]
}
```

But this code doesn't work. How am I supposed to set the default value of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values for union fields correspond to the [first schema in the union](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schema_record). If the default value is an array, then the array schema should be the first schema in the union.

```
"type": [
  {
    "type": "array",
    "items": "com.example.Bar"
  },
  "null"
],
```

Comment: It works after removing the "null" from the types. I guess if I allow null for array field then I cannot pre-populate the default fields with values other than null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I was allowing "null" to be the type for the array field. I guess if I want to pre-populate the default fields with values I cannot allow null.

So the following code fixes the problem.

```
{
  "name": "bars",
  "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": "com.example.Bar"
  },
  "default": [{"name": "bar1", "number":1}, {"name": "bar2", "number":2}, {"name": "bar3", "number":3}]
}
```